# What is the point of a greenhouse?

Tags: greenhouse

How does putting my plants in a greenhouse help them grow? Is it purely to shield them from cold weather, or are there other benefits?

Answer (score 29, accepted):

There are several benefits of a greenhouse:

- accumulation of heat from the sun
- possibility to regulate temperature and humidity
- Protection from wind and excessive rain
- protection from unwelcome pollens
- limited protection from pests especially birds.

Typically you put in a greenhouse plants that prefer a warmer climate than the local one.

Answer (score 13):

Primarily, greenhouses trap heat and moisture.

Most plants prefer things warm and damp, so it's an ideal environment for growing fruit and germinating seeds.

Answer (score 12):

Green houses can extend your growing season, and even allow you to grow throughout the year.